# hyperlinks in biblatex

Tags: hyperref, spacing, biblatex

I'm making a `biblatex` style to solve an issue with the standard styles: if you have a reference with a `doi` field, it just prints the DOI number, with a clickable link if `hyperref` is enabled.

But a DOI number is big and ugly; no one wants to see it. I want to make the link anchored behind the journal reference: beginning with the journal name and ending with the pages. So far I managed to make the following code:

```
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{article}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{bytranslator+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{version}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \href{http://dx.doi.org/\thefield{doi}}{\usebibmacro{journal+issuetitle}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{note+pages}}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{issn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}
```

But there's a problem: as the punctuation and spacing is actually produced by the first `\printfield` after `\newunit\newblock`, they are captured by the `\href`, and the result is very ugly. Is there a way to force them to be produced before the journal title, and the next one exactly after `\usebibmacro{note+pages}`? In other words, can I make the link environment to begin exactly at the journal name, and include the punctuation after `note+pages`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've found a way (thanks to Mr. Lehman!)

As `\href` changes the formatting, it's best to use it inside a `biblatex` formatting primitive, so it will get handled consistently. The code is

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{doilink}{\href{http://dx.doi.org/\thefield{doi}}{#1}}
```

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{article}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{bytranslator+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{version}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printtext[doilink]{\usebibmacro{journal+issuetitle}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{note+pages}}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{issn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

Of course, one should add some logic (`\iffieldundef{doi}`, `\ifhyperref`); I only decided to keep the example simple.