# adding doi-hyperlinks to journal, volume, issue, year, pages in the bibliography

Tags: biblatex, hyperref, doi

I am trying to make a hyperlink in my bibliography referring the doi-url. The url begins with journal name and ends with the pages. Do to this I am using the code provided by Mateus Araújo in [hyperlinks in biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2777/hyperlinks-in-biblatex). Unfortunately this also changes the style. For example, a normal reference looks likes this

[image]

But after adding the code do make the doi-hyperlink, it adds a dot after year and starts with a an uppercase letter.

[image]

I would like to remove the dot and start with a lowercase letter, but don't know how do that.

Here is a the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backref=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples}

\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{doi=false}
\DeclareFieldFormat{doilink}{
\iffieldundef{doi}{#1}
{\href{http://dx.doi.org/\thefield{doi}}{#1}}}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{article}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{bytranslator+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{version}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{in:}%
  \href{http://dx.doi.org/\thefield{doi}}{%
  \usebibmacro{journal+issuetitle}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{note+pages}}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
   {\printfield{issn}}
   {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}
  }

\begin{document}
\cite{kastenholz}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: You might be able to rephrase your question title so that it matches your questions better.

Comment: I hope the new title makes it clearer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the linked question is used another bibliography driver.

**EDIT 2:**
Comment by maetra:

> I recognized that using this together with any of the author-year
>   styles results in an extra space after the link if no pages are
>   defined. Maybe you know a solution?

*Solution:*

In the version 1.6 of biblatex is a small bug in the file `authoryear.bbx`. The style redefine the macro `issue+date`. The redefinition of the macro depends on the option `mergedate`. If the option is set to `true` or `compact` the redefinition is as follows:

```
\renewbibmacro*{issue+date}{%
  \iffieldundef{issue}
    {}
    {\printtext[parens]{\printfield{issue}}}
  \newunit}%
```

Before the last `\newunit` work there is a none escaped space which results in the extra space. So you have to do this:

```
\renewbibmacro*{issue+date}{%
  \iffieldundef{issue}
    {}
    {\printtext[parens]{\printfield{issue}}}%
  \newunit}%
```

This fixes the problem.

**EDIT 1**: Changed Code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,backref=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{doi=false}
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{doi=false}
\DeclareFieldFormat{doilink}{%
\iffieldundef{doi}{#1}%
{\href{http://dx.doi.org/\thefield{doi}}{#1}}}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{article}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{bytranslator+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{version}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{in:}%
  \printtext[doilink]{%
  \usebibmacro{journal+issuetitle}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{note+pages}%
  }%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{issn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}


\begin{document}
\cite{kastenholz}\qquad\cite{herrmann}\qquad\cite{sigfridsson}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks Marco, this solves the problem of the period and the capital letter, unfortunately it adds two spaces after "In:"

Comment: @maetra: The additional space based on the definition `\DeclareFieldFormat{doilink}{`. There I forgot to end the line with `%`

Comment: this code is not working anymore, it seems as if you made too many changes

Comment: @maetra: The code works well for me.

Comment: @maetry: What's your problem. Has you recognised that I use `backend=biber`. I use biblatex v1.6.

Comment: @Marco What about `pages`?

Comment: @Audrey: What do you mean with page?

Comment: @Marco The OP mentions that the DOI link "begins with journal name and ends with the pages". Try adding a citation to a reference with a `pages` field.

Comment: @Marco, sorry I didnt try out with biber, now it works, thanks a lot, just one more thing: I my opinion \bibhyperlink should be replaced with \href

Comment: @maetra: Together we strong.

Comment: @Marco, I recognized that using this together with any of the `author-year` styles results in an extra space after the link if no pages are defined. Maybe you know a solution?

Comment: @maetra: Do you have extra settings?

Comment: @maetra: Please see my edit.

Comment: @Marco, that works great. Now everything looks the way it's supposed to

Answer (score 1):

Marco's solution worked fine for me too. Just for some reason the year was missing in the references when I used his answer. So added these two lines to his code

```
\newunit
\space(\usebibmacro{date})%
```

to include the year as well. Also I used [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48400/biblatex-make-title-hyperlink-to-dois-url-or-isbn) to make hyperlinks for urls or isbns whenever doi is not available. Below is the modified version of Marco's code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,backref=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}


\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{doi=false}
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{doi=false}
\DeclareFieldFormat{doilink}{%
  \iffieldundef{doi}{%
    \iffieldundef{url}{%
      \iffieldundef{isbn}{%
        \iffieldundef{issn}{%
          #1%
        }{%
          \href{http://books.google.com/books?vid=ISSN\thefield{issn}}{#1}%
        }%
      }{%
        \href{http://books.google.com/books?vid=ISBN\thefield{isbn}}{#1}%
      }%
    }{%
      \href{\thefield{url}}{#1}%
    }%
  }{%
    \href{http://dx.doi.org/\thefield{doi}}{#1}%
  }%
}
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{article}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}\addcomma\space%
  \newunit
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{bytranslator+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{version}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printtext[doilink]{%
  \usebibmacro{journal+issuetitle}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{note+pages}%
  \newunit
  \space(\usebibmacro{date})%
  }%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{issn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

\begin{document}
\cite{kastenholz}\qquad\cite{herrmann}\qquad\cite{sigfridsson}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```