# JHEP style citations using biblatex

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bibliographystyle

I am trying to build a CV which will contain two seperate list of papers I have authored, one for published papers and the other for preprints. I know I can do this quite easily using biblatex but I am unable to find the appropriate citation style.

I would ideally like to display my papers in the style specified by [JHEP](https://jhep.sissa.it/jhep/help/JHEP_TeXclass.jsp) but JHEP provides pnly a bst file. I know it is not possible to convert bst files into a format that can be used by biblatex and hence I would like some pointers regarding how I can achive this by modifying, say, biblatex-nature.

In particular, I would like the citations to be displayed as shown in the following examples.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Notice that the details of the published paper is hyperlinked to the doi of the paper and the arxiv number is separately linked to the arXiv url. The citation also conatins a link to the entry in the INSPIRE database but I would not mind if it is not possible to include the INSPIRE link but I need to have the other two links.

I would really appreciate your help, I am very new to using biblatex.

Comment: If you're happy with what the `.bst` style would give you, maybe there is no need to switch to `biblatex`? Or do you need some of its advanced features? You can use additional packages to have separate bibliographies with BibTeX as well (https://ctan.org/pkg/bibtopic, https://ctan.org/pkg/multibib), though it is not as comfortable as with `biblatex`.

Comment: For the links you could have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27752/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/48400/35864 and linked questions.

Comment: For the INSPIRE link you can follow https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/155532/35864 as you will need a new field since `eprint` is taken by the arXiv links.

Comment: Hi, @moewe. As I said I need multiple bibliographies but I am unable to get it right with bibtex and multibib. One reason is that there's no way to distinguish published papers and preprints since both are formatted as articles. Biblatex is not only easier to use than multibib when it comes to generation multiple bibliographies, you can distinguish different papers using the keywords tag.