# biblatex: make "authors" hyperlink to DOIs, URL or ISBN and url breaklink issue in hyperref

Tags: biblatex, hyperref, urls, doi

This is a follow up question to  [biblatex: Make title hyperlink to doi url (if available)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23832/biblatex-make-title-hyperlink-to-doi-url-if-available) and [biblatex: make title hyperlink to DOIs, URL or ISBN](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48400/biblatex-make-title-hyperlink-to-dois-url-or-isbn)!

First , I have an issue with breaklinks=true because the urls don't break up and I have to turn breaklinks on but at the same time , if I turn on it, these links are no longer be clickable.
[image: breaklinks=false]
Here is the code from [Herbert](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23832/biblatex-make-title-hyperlink-to-doi-url-if-available).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex} 
\usepackage[colorlinks,breaklinks=false]{hyperref}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples}
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{doi=false}
\newbibmacro{string+doi}[1]{%
  \iffieldundef{doi}{#1}{\href{http://dx.doi.org/\thefield{doi}}{#1}}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{title}{\usebibmacro{string+doi}{\mkbibemph{#1}}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{\usebibmacro{string+doi}{\mkbibquote{#1}}}
\begin{document}
A reference to~\cite{kastenholz} and~\cite{sigfridsson}. 
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Second, I would like to know how I can change this to "authors" instead of "title". Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

So finally I ended up putting all other people's work together. [(1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34119/biblatex-formatting)[,2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27752/adding-doi-hyperlinks-to-journal-volume-issue-year-pages-in-the-bibliography?lq=1)[,3](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2777/hyperlinks-in-biblatex?lq=1)[,4).](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48400/biblatex-make-title-hyperlink-to-dois-url-or-isbn)Hope I included everyone. Here is the combined code.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf} 

\usepackage[pdftex,colorlinks]{hyperref}

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex} 


\bibliography{biblatex-examples}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%This part in in bbx file.

\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{doi=false}
\DeclareFieldFormat{doilink}{%
    \iffieldundef{doi}{%
    \iffieldundef{url}{%
     #1%
    }{%
      \href{\thefield{url}}{#1}%
    }%
  }{
   \href{http://dx.doi.org/\thefield{doi}}{#1}
   }%
}


\DeclareBibliographyDriver{article}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
   \printtext[doilink]{%
  \usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
  }%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock%
  \addperiod%
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \addperiod%
  \newunit\newblock%
  \usebibmacro{journal+issuetitle}%
  \newunit\newblock%
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}%
    {\printfield{issn}}%
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock%
  \addperiod%
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
\cite{kastenholz}\qquad\cite{herrmann}\qquad\cite{sigfridsson}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Here is the screen shot. Enjoy. This one going to pick DOI first and if  DOI is not available , it would find url. Thanks everyone!
[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

To use `breaklinks=true` in hyperref, use pdftex. For example in Texshop, I was able to run [in Alternative Typesetting Mode.](http://pages.uoregon.edu/koch/Documentation.pdf)

```
%!TEX TS-program = pdflatex  
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex} 
\usepackage[colorlinks,breaklinks=true]{hyperref}
```

For the second part,  I have no idea. :)