# How to produce bibliography hyperlinking journal title with url?

Tags: bibtex, hyperref, urls

BibTeX exported from scientific journals usually have all the informations you need to cite them; one of them is the url. For saving space i would prefer to hyperlink the name of the journal rather than printing the whole url. One way to do such thing would be by writing the url as an `\href` before the journal name in the `.bib` file like so

```
@article{Reference7,
   author = "Zwicker, Judith and Lovett, Ronald",
   title = "When does a pair correlation function fix the state of an equilibrium system?",
   journal =    "\href{http://scitation.aip.org/content/aip/journal/jcp/93/9/10.1063/1.458944}{The Journal of Chemical Physics}",
   year = "1990",
   volume = "93",
   number = "9",
   pages = "6752-6755",
   url = "",
   doi = "http://dx.doi.org/10.1063/1.458944" 
}
```

which will generate a the desired form, that is

[image]

My question is: since I have a huge number of citations, is there a procedure to achieve the same result in an automated fashion, because in this case I have copied the url from its previous position (`url = " here "`) to where it is now.
Thanks

Comment: Did you try the new way via [biblatex](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) and [biber](http://ctan.org/pkg/biber)?

Comment: @ Ruben Thanks
@Paul No, I'm using bibtex; do you think its worth?

Comment: @Manfredo You may read this [answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/5105/14500)... and this [list of questions](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/biblatex?sort=votes&pageSize=50).

Comment: Ok the answer is probably here (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/157093/biblatex-make-authors-hyperlink-to-dois-url-or-isbn-and-url-breaklink-issue)

Comment: The doi is enough and url useless. Your doi field should be: doi = "10.1063/1.458944" and should include a link when compiled no? In which case a link on the title as requested is not needed any more.

Comment: It is misleading to use the journal title to link to the particular article. I would expect that link to take me to the journal's homepage. It would be more appropriate to link the DOI, as @pluton suggests. BibLaTeX has sophisticated facilities for this kind of case, including hyperlinked `eprint`s which you can configure globally by type (so you just specify the identifier and the type in your `.bib` file). Definitely space and effort efficient!

Comment: Ok thanks for the suggestion, in this case I've seen that both links redirect to the article's page but I agree that it is more reasonable to link the doi. By the way this is the Journal of Chemical Physics type of formatting but they don't provide the [.bst] file.