# How to change hyper link from url to journal name?

Tags: hyperref

I am using clean thesis and i want to change hyper link from url to journal name. Please suggest[image: we have add screen shot in which we want to change blue url to journal name (highlighted in yellow)].

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
    \cite{Vandewalle}
    \bibliography{mybib}
    \bibliographystyle{plain}
\end{document}
```

with `mybib.bib`:

```
@article{Vandewalle,
    title = {Symmetry breaking in a few-body system with magnetocapillary interactions},
    author = {Vandewalle, N. and Clermont, L. and Terwagne, D.},
    journal = {\href{http://link.aps.org/doi/10.1103/PhysRevE.85.041402}{Phys. Rev. E}},
    volume = {85},
    number = {4},
    year = {2012},
    pages = {041402}
}
```

results in

[image]

Is this what you want? For future questions, please include a minimal working example (MWE) which shows what you have done so far, this saves the community the trouble of having to re-type your code.

Comment: My question is: since I have a around 120  citations, is there a procedure to achieve the same result in an automated fashion.

Comment: In LaTeX itself this is probably difficult, with `biblatex` it is possible I think, but not easy. The fastest way would be to write a small script in a programming language you are familiar with (such as perl, python, Java) to move the url field to the journal field. The community here can help you with that is necessary.

Comment: see also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/214191/how-to-produce-bibliography-hyperlinking-journal-title-with-url?rq=1 and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/157093/biblatex-make-authors-hyperlink-to-dois-url-or-isbn-and-url-breaklink-issue